# How can I pass a Userform object to a subroutine as an argument?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a subroutine that will set the initial position for a userform when it is started.  This one, taken straight from the internet, works perfectly when run in the form's initialize subroutine:-

```
Private Sub subSetFormPosition()

    Dim Top As Double, Left As Double

    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Top = Abs(Application.Top) + (Application.Height) - (Me.Height + 20)
    Left = Abs(Application.Left) + (Application.Width) - (Me.Width + 100)
    Me.Top = Top
    Me.Left = Left

End Sub
```

However, I should like a subroutine that can be called from within any form.  I tried this 'generalisation':-

```
Public Sub subSetFormPosition(frm As MSForms.UserForm, ivHOffset As Integer, ivVOffset As Integer)
    
    Dim Top As Double, Left As Double
    
    frm.StartUpPosition = 0
    Top = Abs(Application.Top) + (Application.Height) - (frm.Height + ivVOffset)
    Left = Abs(Application.Left) + (Application.Width) - (frm.Width + ivHOffset)
    frm.Top = Top
    frm.Left = Left

End Sub
```

called by

```
    subSetFormPosition frmTimes, 200, 20
```

Running this gives "Run-time error 438:  Object doesn't support this property or method." when it reaches the statement "frm.StartUpPosition = 0".  Userforms do have a StartUpPosition property, so I cannot be passing the form object across to the subroutine correctly.

How can I pass the form object to the subroutine?  I have similar subroutines where I can pass ListBox and Combobox objects successfully, but the form object won't play ball.

Comment: Try `Public Sub subSetFormPosition(frm As frmTimes ...)`

Comment: Try `Public Sub subSetFormPosition(frm As Object,...`

Comment: UserForms do have a `.StartupPosition` but it may not be able to be set at run time with VBA.

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008.  That worked perfectly.